# C incomparable types when trying to allocate an array

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I have a two-dimensional array of fixed length in C,
How can I allocate memory for it, so I will be able to use it 
out of the function scope? (When trying to use `malloc/calloc` the compiler
says `you cant convert void* / char** to char[FIXED][FIXED]`)

[update from comment:]

So I'll just say what I'm trying to do:

A function I wrote should return a list (implemented as a struct) of 2D arrays it creates, but as they are creates as local variables they 'die' and can't be returned / reached afterwards

Comment: Either use arrays and you don't need to allocate, or use pointers and allocate.

Comment: How can I use arrays and return local variables?

Comment: You cannot dynamically allocate memory for arrays - use Vectors or pointers instead.
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/416/

Comment: So I'll just say what I'm trying to do: A function I wrote should return a list (implemented as a struct) of 2D arrays it creates, but as they are creates as local variables they 'die' and can't be returned / reached afterwards.

Comment: Make a copy on the heap, populate it with the same data and then return a pointer to it (decayed functionalities)

Comment: Or stick the array into a struct, then you can return it by value...

Comment: How can I make a copy on the heap?

Comment: @KerrekSB - How can I make a copy on the heap from inside a function?

Comment: Please show the code you have. This will make it easier for everybody to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate dynamic memory for an array with C VLAs (`char **` is the wrong type though):

```
int nrows, ncols;
char (*array)[ncols] = malloc(ncols * nrows);
```

Comment: You don't need VLAs for it (size of the array is `FIXED`, which seems to be a macro)

Comment: Nor do VLAs have the correct lifetime that's required by the problem.

Comment: VLA's does not only refer to the stack allocatable ones, but also VLA types.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, arrays are not pointers.
In particular, arrays of arrays are not pointers to pointers.
(To see this clearly, draw them on paper.)

However, an array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element in certain contexts, such as when being passed as a parameter to or returned from a function.

So, an array of arrays can be converted into a pointer to an array:

```
int a[3][4];
int (*b)[4] = a; /* b is a pointer to an array of four elements - the first element of a */
```

And returning one from a function (this one is a mess to read):

```
int (*make_stuff(size_t size))[4]
{
    return malloc(size * sizeof(int[4]));
}
```

But the whole pointer-to-array syntax is quite messy and unreadable and almost impossible to get right.
I personally find these get more readable if you use a typedef:

```
typedef int row[4];
row a[3];
row *b = a;
row *c = malloc(3 * sizeof(row));

row* make_stuff(size_t size)
{
    return malloc(size * sizeof(row));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array of fixed length is stored in automatic storage i.e., Stack which remains in the function scope. To store the variable in Heap storage, you have to allocate memory for that dynamically using malloc/calloc.

For example( 2D Array )

```
// N x M array
char **a = malloc( sizeof *a * N ) ;
if( a == NULL )
{
 // Error allocating memory
 return -1 ;
}

for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
 a[i] = malloc( sizeof * a[i] * M ) ;
}
```

For example( 1D Array ),

```
void SomeFunc( void )
{    
 char a[10] ; // will be stored in stack (function scope)

 char *b ; // declare a pointer that points to char memory.
 b = malloc( 10 * sizeof(char) ) ; 
 if( b == NULL )
 {
  // Error in allocating memory
  return -1 ;
 }
 // will be stored in Heap (scope = till you free the memory)

 //... Your code goes here...
 //... Call to other functions 

 free( b ) ;
}
```

Also, you can make it `global` or `static`, if you do not want to use `malloc/calloc`.

Ex:

```
char a[10] = {0} ; // Global variable, stored in Data segment
void SomeFunc( void )
{
 static char b[10] = {0} ; // static variable, stored in Data segment
}
```

The scope for variables stored in Data segment will be through out the execution. So you can use them, even outside the `SomeFunc()`

Comment: This code is good for one-dimensional array. OP's code probably looks like this (just guessing); it doesn't work because OP wants to work with a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @anatolyg: I was giving the OP an idea towards dynamic memory allocation as he/she was trying to malloc an automatic variable. I have added the code for 2D too :-)